# Visual Studio for Mac exits while Build of React-Template with return code 127 cause Node not found

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I've created a blank React-Redux project on my Big Sur Mac with Visual Studio (not Code). Then I tried to build it but build process ends with

```
/Users/xxx/Development/TimeCounter/TimeCounter/TimeCounter.csproj(5,5): Warning MSB3073: Der Befehl "node --version" wurde mit dem Code 127 beendet. (MSB3073) (TimeCounter)
```

But if I go to terminal the same command works and bin folder of node is also present in `PATH` variable.

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is due to Visual Studio for Mac not finding node on its PATH. The Terminal has a different PATH environment variable compared with GUI applications, such as Visual Studio for Mac.

You can run Visual Studio for Mac from the Terminal in order for it to use the same PATH. `open -n "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"` However that is not ideal.

Not sure where your node is installed, running `which node` will return the path to it. For me this returns `/usr/local/bin/node`. The `/usr/local/bin` directory is one directory that Visual Studio for Mac will add to its PATH environment variable, so a workaround here would be to setup a symlink in the `/usr/local/bin` directory for node.

Answer (score 0):

VS for Mac needs to be opened from Terminal

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio & dotnet dev-certs https
```

credit: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/1574#issuecomment-701950771